# Scala Enumeration to HList with shapeless

Tags: scala, enums, shapeless, scala-macros, hlist

Supposing there is a regular Scala Enumeration object, something like

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
  type WeekDay = Value
  val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
}
```

Is it possible to transform it to shapeless HList without explicitly specifying full HList's type signature? I have come across ProductArgs which almost what I need, but it still needs to be fed each enum value as separate arguments. At the same time compiler does know the type and the size of enums collection so it must be possible.

Comment: First of all, you should change your singleton name `WeekDay` by something else, like `MyWeekDay`, as WeekDay already exists in Scala (`org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.WeekDay`).

Comment: The name does not matter, I simply copied it from scaladoc for Enumeration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
import shapeless.HList
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

object Macros {
  object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
    type WeekDay = Value
    val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
  }

  trait ToHList {
    type T <: HList
  }

  def toHList(enum: Enumeration): ToHList = macro impl

  def impl(c: whitebox.Context)(enum: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val enum1 = c.eval(c.Expr[Enumeration](c.untypecheck(enum)))
    val valueNames = enum1.values.toList.map(_.toString)
    val tpe = valueNames.foldLeft[c.Tree](tq"shapeless.HNil")(
      (acc, v) => tq"shapeless.::[$enum.${TermName(v)}.type, $acc]"
    )
    q"new Macros.ToHList { type T = $tpe }"
  }
}

import Macros._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Reify
val tohlist = toHList(WeekDay)
Reify[tohlist.T].apply() // Sun :: Sat :: Fri :: Thu :: Wed :: Tue :: Mon :: HNil
```

Comment: Thanks! I am a total noob in macros so it all looks like some serious magic to me. It works as intended but perhaps defeats my purpose of making the code DRY by making it convoluted instead. Is it also possible to define a _type_ based on enum size? For example, a plain Tuple7 or HList of Seq[Int]'s?

Comment: @NebehrGudahtt `shapeless.ops.hlist.Tupler` transforms an HList into Tuple. So you can do `val hlist = Reify[tohlist.T].apply()` `Tupler[tohlist.T].apply(hlist)` or `hlist.tupled`.

Comment: Thanks but this is not quite what I meant. I would like to generate type T so that `type T = Seq[Int] :: Seq[Int] :: Seq[Int] :: Seq[Int] :: Seq[Int] :: Seq[Int] :: Seq[Int] :: Seq[Int] :: HNil` or equivalent tuple, where the number of elements corresponds to enumeration size.

Comment: @NebehrGudahtt Use `shapeless.ops.hlist.Fill` and `shapeless.ops.hlist.Length`. You can introduce a type class `trait MkSeqHList[L <: HList] {
    type Out <: HList
  }`
  `object MkSeqHList {
    implicit def mkSeqHList[L <: HList, N <: Nat](implicit
                                                  length: Length.Aux[L, N],
                                                  fill: Fill[N, Seq[Int]]
                                                 ): MkSeqHList[L] { type Out = fill.Out } =
      new MkSeqHList[L] { type Out = fill.Out }
  }`.

Comment: @NebehrGudahtt Then `val mkSeqHList = the[MkSeqHList[tohlist.T]]`
  `type T = mkSeqHList.Out` or ``type T = the.`MkSeqHList[tohlist.T]`.Out``.